# Inexplicable NullPointerException, or so it seems

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, derby

I am using JavaDB and Derby to modify a database. I was trying to create a view with

```
statement.executeUpdate(SQLUpdate);
```

where `SQLUpdate` was the query that is the SQL command to create the view, but for some reason, Java throws NullPointerException on SQLUpdate EVEN THOUGH I HAVE IT DECLARED LIKE SO: `private String SQLUpdate;`. //I have first tried to declare it as local variable, but then moved to declaring it as a private variable available to the whole class. If this were C++, I would MAKE this work, but given that this is Java, I don't have access to the pointerbusiness.

Can someone give me a diagnosis as to why Java might be throwing NullPointerException? //I have read the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29 (look for `executeUpdate()`), but it doesn't say ANYTHING about storing your SQL Query to a String variable and then using `executeUpdate(myStringVariable);`

Comment: Declare -> Initialize -> Use it.

Comment: Your `statement` object is probably `null`. NPE occurs when you try to call a method on an Object that is null.

Comment: You mean saying something like `SQLUpdate = "CREATE VIEW myView AS SELECT ";` somewhere in the constructor (or in the method where I use this variable, and then continue with business as usual?

Comment: please post the full stacktrace

Comment: The problem is fixed. I made a simple logic error that I should have seen earlier // maybe I should take a break....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java throws `NullPointerException` (usually abbreviated NPE) when you try to invoke a method or reference a property on an object that is null.

As mentioned in the above comment, your `statement` object is likely null. Alternatively, something inside of the statement's `executeUpdate` method may be trying to access a `null` property in that manner.

If you look at the stack trace, it should tell you exactly which line produced the error, and that help you diagnose which object is null.

Comment: I did the most basic of errors. //it is fixed now.

Comment: Some functions will throw NPE when you pass them null too.

Comment: @BaileyS yes, you will get errors when passing in null Integers where primitive int was expected as well

Comment: @Shadow Creeper Indeed, but never for no reason :)

Answer (score 1):

As you writed it, it seems that you forgot to **initialize** your variable `SQLUpdate`. After declared it, you should initialized it **before** using it in the `executeUpdate` method. Hence, you get the NPE.

You could execute direclty your query like that :

```
s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO MYLIBRARY.MYTABLE (NAME, ID) VALUES ('RICH', 123)");
```

Or if you created a variable like you :

```
private String SQLUpdate;

//in your code/method/etc..
SQLUpdate = "INSERT INTO MYLIBRARY.MYTABLE (NAME, ID) VALUES ('RICH', 123)";
s.executeUpdate(SQLUpdate);
```

Your `statement` object could also be `null`.
[Here's](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzaha/stateex.htm) a link, which show an example to do basic operations with the db.

Answer (score 0):

If you only declared `SQLUpdate` as you mentioned it will have the default value. The default value of an object attribute in Java is `null`, which is causing the `NullPointerException`. You need to set your SQL to the `SQLUpdate` attribute to make it work.